# Esper engine:Can't I use '<' or '>' after 'inner join on'?

Tags: java, esper

The EPL as follows :

```
   select * from EventObject(name='abc')#win(2 min) e1 inner join EventObject(name='bcd')#win(2 min) e2 on e1.length > e2.length
```

But, there is an error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.espertech.esper.client.EPStatementSyntaxException: Incorrect syntax near '>' expecting an equals '=' but found a greater then '>' at line 1 column 114, please check the outer join within the from clause [select * from EventObject(name='abc')#win(2 min) e1 inner join EventObject(name='bcd')#win(2 min) e2 on e1.length > e2.length ]
    at com.espertech.esper.epl.parse.ExceptionConvertor.convertStatement(ExceptionConvertor.java:46)
    at com.espertech.esper.epl.parse.ParseHelper.parse(ParseHelper.java:111)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPAdministratorHelper.compileEPL(EPAdministratorHelper.java:84)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPAdministratorHelper.compileEPL(EPAdministratorHelper.java:67)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPAdministratorImpl.createEPLStmt(EPAdministratorImpl.java:104)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPAdministratorImpl.createEPL(EPAdministratorImpl.java:63)
    at esper.demo.HelloEsper5.main(HelloEsper5.java:27)
```

Answer (score 1):

The on-clause only allows equals '='. You can leave it off however and using the 
'where' or 'having'.

Comment: From Esper documentation 8.8.0 http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.8.0/reference-esper/html_single/#epl-outerjoin ... 
If the optional on clause is specified, it may only employ the = equals operator and property names.
Any other operators must be placed in the where-clause. The stream names that appear in the
on clause may refer to any stream in the from-clause